# add images to additional info product tab

Tags: product, attributes, additional-information

I'm newbie in magento, I have to add image instead of text in one value of the additional info tab in the product's page.
How can I do this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Catalog>>attributes>>manage attributes>>Add new attribute.
Give any name for attribute id, select 'media image' from drop down box. Select Store view/Global view/Website view based on your requirements. Give a name in Admin(Label name), save it. Clear cache and re-index. Go to manage attribute sets, you will see unorganized attribute on right side, drag it into any group, save it. Then go to products tab, you should see that attribute in products form. We can do this programatically. But you are a newbie and may break down your magento, so let us stick with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute with the input type 'Media Image'. Assign the attribute to your Attribute Set and you will be able to add an image when you edit the product.