# Magento, how can i edit Additional Info for products

Tags: magento-1.9, additional-information

I need to add product_id to products Additional Info, how can I do this?

I see this,[add images to additional info product tab](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24683/add-images-to-additional-info-product-tab)
but I don't understand, how do I choose their product id, and add him to additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Product id in Additional info tab you have to copy file from

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

To your theme like

> app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme_name]/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

and replace the below code to this file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Product additional attributes template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes
 */
?>
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__('Product Id')) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getId(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

I have added the below additional code to this file

```
<tr>
   <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__('Product Id')) ?></th>
   <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getId(); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Hope this will work for you.